# VBA to apply formats down a table

Tags: excel, vba, format, paint

I have a set of 227 workbooks to run this macro on. I start with a list of workbook names at a given filepath. For each file, the macro opens it, goes to a specified sheet, copies the first line of a table, and then format-paints that down through the rest of the sheet/table. It loops through each workbook until it's done all workbooks. For some reason, I'm getting a debug error on the `PasteSpecial` function, and I'm not quite sure why. The workbook and sheet references are valid, I've triple-checked them. Any glaring issues I'm overlooking?

```
Sub Macro2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("H6")

If Right(Path, 1) <> "\" Then
    Path = Path & "\"
End If

wsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F10")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("A2:B20000").ClearContents
OutLn = 2
Line = 1

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Line, 1) <> ""
    OpnFil = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(Line, 1)
    Workbooks.Open fileName:=Path & OpnFil, UpdateLinks:=False
    ScanLn = 12
        Do While Workbooks(OpnFil).Sheets(wsheet).Range("A8:V8").Copy
            Workbooks(OpnFil).Sheets(wsheet).Cells.Range("A10:V1000000").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Loop
    Workbooks(OpnFil).Close
    Line = Line + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you have a `Do While` loop to `Copy`?

Comment: Glaring issues 1) you have an infinite loop `Do While ... .Copy` 2) you are `pastespecial`'g to 1,000,000 rows. Why? seems excessive 3) you arn't taking advantage of the fact `... .Open` returns a reference to the opened workbook 4) myou probably want to save the workbook before closing it., 5) you arn't `Dim`'g your variables

Comment: You got your cart before the horse. Initially, you don't have 227 workbooks but merely one. And you don't have to open it because it's already open. This leads you to wanting a procedure to which you pass an open workbook as an argument. Therefore, the procedure that opens the workbook is another one. And once you have come to that point you may add a loop to it that repeats the procedure call 227 times with a changing argument. That will be the last step of development.

Comment: Sorry, for clarity, the macro tool sits in its own workbook ```ThisWorkbook``` while ```OpnFil``` references each file that is opened. the first ```DoWhile``` opens the first workbook on the list, the second ```DoWhile``` format pastes down the entirety of the sheet (some of the workbooks will have 1M-line tables, hence the 1,000,000 rows. The files open in autosave mode, so no need to tell the Macro to save. Then the file is closed and the next one is opened.